# Google Maps Iframe gives "XMLHttpRequest cannot load"

Tags: google-maps, iframe, xmlhttprequest, cors

When using an iframe to display a Google Map that a client has set up, I keep getting

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mymaps&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/maps/d/gen204?a%3D58%26width%3D525%26height%3D295%26s%3D7&followup=https://www.google.com/maps/d/gen204?a%3D58%26width%3D525%26height%3D295%26s%3D7. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.google.com' is therefor now allowed access.

I know about using JSONP when accessing a json-object, but that's not really what I'm trying to do here as far as I can tell.

The code for the iframe is simply:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=CLIENTS_IDmsa=0&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=11&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Is it possible that I need some sort of key to use this map?

The map is displayed, but I want to get rid of the errors in the console.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you provided: https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=CLIENTS_IDmsa=0&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=11&output=embed does not work for the public. A working iframe src would be something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2624.9983685732213!2d2.29432085!3d48.85824149999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d%3A0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!2sgoogle+map+paris+eiffel+tower!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sbe!4v1387990714927" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

And a working jsfiddle [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/T7jLf/20/)

And here's a [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) for on google map iframe.

Enjoy!!